# How to use setByte in a fragment?

Tags: java, android

I'm using `felipecsl/GifImageView` library from `github`

```
public class Send extends Fragment {
    ImageView gifView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.send, container, false);
        return rootView;

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        gifView = getView().findViewById(R.id.gifView);
        gifView.setBytes(bitmapData);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to go through the library before you start using them. You're using `ImageView` instead of `GifImageView` in your code.

Rather then using the default `ImageView` you should be using `GifImageView` provided by the library as mentioned in [sample example here](https://github.com/felipecsl/GifImageView/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/felipecsl/gifimageview/app/MainActivity.java).

Comment: thanks it works! stupid me overlooked those 3 letters.

Comment: Glad it worked. Kindly accept the answer if it was helpful for you.